# Jquery getJSON on Document.ready()

Tags: jquery, json, dom, load

I need a hint on how to resolve this issue, this is my jquery script calling the JSON

```
$('#myTabs a').click(function () {
    var jsonURL = $(this).attr('data-link');
    var targetURL = $(this).attr('href');

      $.getJSON(jsonURL,
        function(data) {
           $(targetURL).html('<p> Name: ' + data.item.name + '</p>' + '<p>Details : ' + data.item.details + '</p>' + '<p> Composition: ' + data.item.composition + '</p>' + '<p> Sex: ' + data.item.modelDetails + '</p>' );
         });
       });
```

While this is the HTML

```
<!-- Navigation Buttons -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="myTabs">
            <li class="active"><a id="test1" data-link="https://api.myjson.com/bins/1rzuh" href="#one">One</a></li>
            <li><a id="test2" data-link="https://api.myjson.com/bins/4a8ax" href="#two">Two</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Content -->
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div data-json="element-1" class="tab-pane active" id="one">wewe1</div>
            <div data-json="element-2" class="tab-pane" id="two">wewe2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Problem is I need the first of the JSONs content to appear inside the target div when DOM completes to load, now all I see is just a blank div because I need first to click on the button before content appears correctly.

I'm really noob in developing so please be patient :)
Thx everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trigger the click event on first element of collection after you define the event handler shown in question

```
$('#myTabs a').first().click();
```

Comment: Hello, thx for answering, could you pls be more specific? Very noob coder here

Comment: more specific about what? You put this after your code and it will have same effect as a user clicking on the first one

Answer (score 0):

If you put the javascript inside a document.ready, then it will automatically run on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // do stuff on page load
});
```